# Title within a title: How to format properly using Chicago style

Tags: formatting, titles, chicago-manual-of-style

Would this be an appropriate way to format the title of my essay, or should it be different? I am using the Chicago style. I am using two book titles within my own title.

Would this be the proper way to format it, or should it be different?

> Comparing “The Greek Alexander Romance” to “Sundiata: An Epic of Old Mali”

Comment: There was an edit to the formatting, but formatting *is* the question. Could the OP just state in words what formatting they are trying to achieve? Web browsers will display text and special symbols (like lines) differently. We can't be sure of your intent if you don't explain it.

Comment: I am trying to find out if I need to put quotes around titles of books when they are in the title of my own essay or if I need to do something different. I am wanting to write in the chicago style formatting. I don't know what else to say to make it more clear.

Comment: My title is: Comparing "The Greek Alexander Romance" to "Sundiata: An Epic of Old Mali"

Comment: unless that was meant for the person who edited my post earlier lol